# ReactJS: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a sample with `adminlte-reactjs` follow this [link](https://github.com/booleanhunter/ReactJS-AdminLTE). But I got an issue:

> /adminlte-reactjs/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in
>   'C:\Users\nem\Documents\reactjs\admin-template\node_modules\adminlte-reactjs\node_modules\react-dom\lib'

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "admin-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "adminlte-reactjs": "^1.0.6",
    "apisauce": "^0.14.3",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "reduxsauce": "^0.7.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Hope I will get solutions from guys, thanks

Comment: Tks so much, fateme fazli :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

or:

```
rm -rf node_modules/react
npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.6 -S
```